# heroku ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'popper.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, popper.js

Hi every one I am new on heroku,

If I clone from github repo and run >npm install and >npm start on computer its working fine, but on my heroku app it showing error:

> Failed to compile ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js Module
>   not found: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in
>   '/app/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'

Heroku app: https://nfq-barber-shop.herokuapp.com/
Github repo: https://github.com/ezopas/nfq-barber-shop
I try run these commands:

```
npm install bootstrap -D
npm install jquery -D
npm install popper.js -D
```

But still its the same error. What I should to do? My app runs totally fine on other computers (npm start).

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nfq-barber-shop-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper-with-scheduler": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery.nicescroll": "^3.7.6",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nav-scroll-spy": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

- Move the modules in `devDependencies` into the `dependencies` section
- Set the config variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to false in the Heroku settings

**Explanation**

Heroku, in a attempt to reduce the bundle output of your project, does not install `devDependencies` when it is setting up your project.

The general rule of Node application development is that all modules that require do not contribute to the running of your application must go into your `devDependencies` and all the modules that do go into the `dependencies`

From the look of your `package.json`, you do not necessarily have to put anything in the `devDependencies` since popper and jQuery **do** belong in the `dependencies` section.

You can alternatively set the `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` variable in Heroku to false, however this is not the recommended approach, because this technically makes the app *not* a production application

Answer (score 0):

Go the the bootstrap documentation website and select the appropriate version of bootstrap you are using.
For bootstrap 4, from the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), add the bootstrapCDN links present in the started template to your index.html file.

For this specific question, add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to your index.html.

Note: check the appropriate version for the scripts.